# How to properly update subviews on Marionette when using constantly updating JSON

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a single page app built with Marionette that has a main view with a list of subviews.

The JSON which holds all application data is updated constantly. I've tried to separate region show code so that it will be run just once and not on every render.

Now the render event is fired on every timeout loop even though the JSON is static data and therefore change event should not call render. What is wrong? I assume it has something to do with .set but is there any other way to load the response from an array variable to the subview collection, since fetch will allow only url attribute and will not accept array variable?

This example is an extremely simplified version of the application code to concentrate on this specific problem.

Controller:

```
var Controller = {

   showMainView: function(id){

     // create model and fetch data on startup
     var mainElement = new mainElement();
     var mainElementFetched = mainElement.fetch({url: 'http://json.json'});

     // fetch done, create view, show view in region, setTimeout
     mainElementFetched.done(function(data){

       var mainElementView = mainElementView({model:mainElement});

       App.mainRegion.show(mainElementView);

       setTimeout(updateJSON, 5000);

     }

     // timeOut loop to check for JSON changes
     var updateJSON = function(){

       mainElement.fetch({url: 'http://json.json'});
       App.timeOut = setTimeout(updateJSON, 5000);

     }

   }
}
```

MainElement Model:

```
MainElement = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse : function(response){
    // parsing code
    return response;
  }
});
```

MainElementView (Layout):

```
MainElementView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: "#main-template",
  initialize:function(){

     //create collection for subelements
     this.subElementCollection = new SubElementCollection();

     //listen to change event, and fire callback only when change in model is detected
     this.model.on('change', this.render, this);

  },
  regions:{
    subsection : ".subsection"
  },
  onShow: function(){
    // show subelements in subsection region when mainelementview is shown on screen, but not show on every render
    this.subsection.show(new SubElementCompositeView({collection:this.subElementCollection}))
  },
  onRender : function(){
    var response = this.model.response;
    // get subelements when change event fires and parse the response
    this.subElementCollection.set(response,{parse:true});
  }

});
```

SubElement Model, Collection, ItemView, CompositeView:

```
SubElement = Backbone.Model.extend({});

SubElementCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model:SubElement,
  comparator : function(model){
    var price = model.get('price');
    return -(price);
  },
  parse:function(response){

    // parsing code to get data to models from differents parts of JSON

    return response;

  }

});

SubElementItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#subelement-template",
  tagName: "tr"


});

SubElementCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: "#subelements-template",
  tagName : "table",
  itemView:SubElementItemView,
  itemViewContainer : "tbody",
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
  },
  appendHtml : function(collectionView,itemView,index){

    // SORTING CODE

  },
  onRender:function(collectionView,itemView,index){

    // ADD IRRELEVANT EXTERNAL STUFF TO TEMPLATE AFTER RENDER

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch). It says:

> ```
> A "change" event will be triggered if the server's state differs from the current attributes.
> ```

In your `MainElementView` where you bind to your model's change event: `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`, you are actually saying every time your model changes, call render.

If re-drawing the whole view is too slow, due to the amount of changes. Why don't you make your rendering more fine-grained? For example you could listen for specific change events and just change the DOM elements which need changing:

```
this.model.on('change:Name', function () {
    this.$('[name=Name]').html(this.model.get('Name'));
}, this);
```

It is more work to set this up, but you could make it a bit cleverer by matching the model property names to your DOM element name or something.

Comment: So just to clarify before I accept your answer: Change event is fired on every fetch even if the JSON data has not changed? The view is re-drawing ok but i thought that rendering it on every fetch would be bad practice if the JSON feed has not changed.

Comment: Ah, I see, so your JSON response is not actually different, but it is still firing the change event? That should not happen, you can see from the quote that it should only call `set` if anything is different in the response from the server. Does the JSON object contain any nested objects? It could be that Backbone is doing a equality comparison between two nested objects, which is returning false and hence Backbone is calling `set` on that property.

Comment: Also as an aside, I would say it is best to bind to your model's change event in your `onRender` method, as render could be called before it is in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm building an app where the JSON will change over time, but if it's polled every 5 seconds there will be no change about 95% of the time. In this example the JSON is a static one to find out why it is constantly firing the change event, maybe I could have said it more clearly. The JSON is heavily nested up to 15 levels. I will try to manually check if javascript thinks JSON data is equal or not between fetch calls.

Comment: I managed to get it working comparing stringified JSON data and triggering render via custom event if they are not equal. I guess this might mean that backbone change event fired by fetch does not always as it is meant.

Comment: And again, as additional information to someone with a similar problem, I think the change event is fired because I do a lot of adding to the json in the parse section. This would mean that backbone is comparing fetched unparsed collection with the current already parsed collection. If this truly is what is happening I would really like a switch of sometype here to change backbone behaviour, should the comparison happen after parse of before.

Comment: Fork the repo an change behaviour yourself!